# Unable to open new pages expect index page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a wordpress blog. Its is working fine in local.
When i copied the same to server expect index page nothing is working. i.e, when i open a new page(ex: "domain.com/contact") it throws "The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.". I changed all the URL like site url, etc ..

Comment: check to see if .htaccess is there on the server and mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: can you log into the admin? domain.com/wp-admin/

Comment: Thanks .htaccess was the problem. i resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just to provide a clear answer based on Shakti's comment...*

It looks like your WP installation is configured to use a custom permalink structure which requires mod_rewrite. It may be that your server does not support mod_rewrite, or the settings are not enabled in `.htaccess`.

Check that your `.htaccess` file was uploaded when you migrated the site and that the correct settings are present. If not you can disable custom permalinks by logging in to WP Admin, going to Options and Permalinks, then choosing the Default option.

Answer (score 2):

you need to change in .htaccess file, text after "dRewriteRule".

i.e,

```
Before : dRewriteRule . /blog/index.php
After  : dRewriteRule . /proj_folder/blog/index.php
```

Here "/proj_folder" is the project folder you kept "blog" files.

make sure that the link is correct.